# Can I disable the login area "shaking" when I get my password wrong?

Tags: greeter

When I get my password wrong it shakes:

[image]

How can I disable this?

Comment: I would imagine you cannot without editing source and changing what I assume would be a CSS animation.

Comment: It is in vala and not CSS

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change. It is hardcoded in Pantheon Greeter (see http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-pantheon/pantheon-greeter/trunk/view/head:/src/LoginBox.vala).

Answer (score -1):

Remove lines 161 to 176 in the file. Then build it from source

THIS IS UNTESTED AND WILL DESTROY YOUR SYSTEM MOST LIKELY AND WILL REQUIRE REINSTALLING OF THE GREETER

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Clone the repository and do my edits in `LoginBox.vala` then compile

Comment: How do I clone the repository and how do I compile it?

Comment: You should not struggle with source code if you don't know what to do. This is dangerous!

Comment: @Tim Look at INSTALL